# How to create a two column collection view list with IGListKit in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iglistkit

I am using IGListKit library([IGListKit](https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit)).
I would like to create a two column collection view list like below.
I have read the IGListKit manual, but I couldn't understand how to achieve that.

I passed the proper width in `sizeForItem`, but the column becomes 1.

Could you give me any advice ?

[image]

***Additional Info***

Following is my code and its output screenshot.

First code is ViewController.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    lazy var adapter: ListAdapter = {
        return ListAdapter(updater: ListAdapterUpdater(), viewController: self)
    }()

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    let channels = [
        Channel(id: "1", color: UIColor.black),
        Channel(id: "2", color: UIColor.blue),
        Channel(id: "3", color: UIColor.red),
        Channel(id: "4", color: UIColor.yellow),
        Channel(id: "5", color: UIColor.green),
        ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.adapter.collectionView = self.collectionView
        self.adapter.dataSource = self
    }

    func objects(for listAdapter: ListAdapter) -> [ListDiffable] {
        return self.channels as! [ListDiffable]
    }

    func listAdapter(_ listAdapter: ListAdapter, sectionControllerFor object: Any) -> ListSectionController {
        return ChannelSectionController()
    }

    func emptyView(for listAdapter: ListAdapter) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }
```

Following is SectionController.

```
final class ChannelSectionController: ListSectionController {

    var channel: Channel?

    override func numberOfItems() -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func sizeForItem(at index: Int) -> CGSize {
        let length = collectionContext!.containerSize.width / 4
        return CGSize(width: length, height: length)
    }

    override func cellForItem(at index: Int) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let channel = channel else {
            fatalError("channel is nil.")
        }

        guard let cell = self.collectionContext?.dequeueReusableCellFromStoryboard(withIdentifier: "ChannelCell", for: self, at: index) as? ChannelCollectionViewCell else {
            fatalError()
        }
        cell.channel = channel // Update the cell label and color.
        return cell
    }

    override func didUpdate(to object: Any) {
        self.channel = object as? Channel
    }

    override func didSelectItem(at index: Int) {}
}
```

As you can see, width which is returned in `sizeForItem()` is enough small than frame width.
However, the output column becomes one line.

[image]

Comment: How you are calculating size for item of CollectionView ?

Comment: Are you subclassing `IGListSectionController`? the size of the cell should be handled in it. Also, are you conforming to the adapter data source (`adapter.dataSource = self`)?

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Thank you for your comments.

@nuridinselimko
I just post the additional info with my original code and screenshot image.
It'd be great if it could help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [this](https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit/blob/master/Guides/Best%20Practices%20and%20FAQ.md) article(at the bottom) how to create an object you should create your object like this:

```
class ChannelCollection: ListDiffable {

var id : String
var channels: [Channel]
init(id: String,channels: [Channel]) {
    self.id = id
    self.channels = channels
}
func isEqual(toDiffableObject object: ListDiffable?) -> Bool {
    return true //compare your object here, I returned true for test
}
func diffIdentifier() -> NSObjectProtocol {
    return id as NSObjectProtocol
}
}
```

and your viewcontroller should look like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,ListAdapterDataSource {
lazy var adapter: ListAdapter = {
    return ListAdapter(updater: ListAdapterUpdater(), viewController: self)
}()
var items : [Any] = []
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
var channelCollection : ChannelCollection?
let channels = [
    Channel(id: "1", color: UIColor.black),
    Channel(id: "2", color: UIColor.blue),
    Channel(id: "3", color: UIColor.red),
    Channel(id: "4", color: UIColor.yellow),
    Channel(id: "5", color: UIColor.green),
    ]

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    collectionView.frame = view.bounds
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.channelCollection = ChannelCollection.init(id: "1", channels: self.channels)
    self.items.append(self.channelCollection as Any)
    self.adapter.collectionView = self.collectionView
    self.adapter.dataSource = self
}

func objects(for listAdapter: ListAdapter) -> [ListDiffable] {
    return self.items as! [ListDiffable]
}

func listAdapter(_ listAdapter: ListAdapter, sectionControllerFor object: Any) -> ListSectionController {
    return ChannelSectionController.init(channelCollection: self.channelCollection!)
}

func emptyView(for listAdapter: ListAdapter) -> UIView? {
    return nil
}}
```

your ListSectionController:

```
final class ChannelSectionController: ListSectionController {

var channel: Channel?

var channelCollection : ChannelCollection?
init(channelCollection: ChannelCollection)
{
    self.channelCollection = channelCollection
}
override func numberOfItems() -> Int {
    return (self.channelCollection?.channels.count)!
}

override func sizeForItem(at index: Int) -> CGSize {
    let length = collectionContext!.containerSize.width / 4
    return CGSize(width: length, height: length)
}

override func cellForItem(at index: Int) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    guard let cell = self.collectionContext?.dequeueReusableCellFromStoryboard(withIdentifier: "ChannelCell", for: self, at: index) as? ChannelCollectionViewCell else {
        fatalError()
    }
    //cell.channel = channel // Update the cell label and color.
    return cell
}

override func didUpdate(to object: Any) {
    self.channel = object as? Channel
}

override func didSelectItem(at index: Int) {}}
```

So what I changed here is that you are adding 5 sections,better practice is to add a single section and 5 rows,this code outputs the thing you want,just try it.

Comment: I have added my code here.
Could you give me any advice ?

Answer (score 3):

**Single cell/Single section**

For those who want to use single-cell per section unlike the accepted answer which uses multiple cells/rows in a single sectionSectionController you just have to use a dedicated layout from IGListKit like so:-

```
let layout = ListCollectionViewLayout(stickyHeaders: false, topContentInset: 0, stretchToEdge: true)
```

This will behave the same way as normal collectionViewLayout by making sure that sections fill the width before making a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the size for each item in your section controller.

Do this by overriding `sizeForItem(at index: Int)` in your section controller.

For example:
Say you have 16 pixels of space between each cell, and want to use a 2 column layout:

```
override func sizeForItem(at index: Int) -> CGSize {
  guard let contextOfCollection = collectionContext, 
    let entry = entry 
    else { 
      return .zero
  }

  let objectWidth = (contextOfCollection.containerSize.width - 16 - 16)/2 // dividing by 2 because
                                                                          // you want 2 columns
  return CGSize(width: objectWidth, height:objectWidth)
}
```

Or you could set a fixed cell size and use insets/autolayout/constraints to pad the cells nicely.